# Get RGB values from AVPicture and change to grey-scale in FFMPEG

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

The main motive of my code is to change the RGB values from the AVPicture in FFMPEG.

I have been able to get the image data "data[0]" by following the article : http://blog.tomaka17.com/2012/03/libavcodeclibavformat-tutorial/

I would like to know that how can I access the 3 bytes of pic.data[0] which is in RGB format. I have been trying to access the pic.data[i][j] via for-loop in 2D matrix fashion but jth element>3.

Any guidance in this regard will be helpful.

Code is here :

```
AVPicture pic;
        avpicture_alloc(&pic, PIX_FMT_RGB24, mpAVFrameInput->width,mpAVFrameInput->height);
        auto ctxt = sws_getContext(mpAVFrameInput->width,mpAVFrameInput->height,static_cast<PixelFormat>(mpAVFrameInput->format),
            mpAVFrameInput->width, mpAVFrameInput->height, PIX_FMT_RGB24, SWS_BILINEAR, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

        if (ctxt == nullptr)
            throw std::runtime_error("Error while calling sws_getContext");
        sws_scale(ctxt, mpAVFrameInput->data, mpAVFrameInput->linesize, 0, mpAVFrameInput->height, pic.data,
            pic.linesize);


    for (int i = 0; i < (mpAVFrameInput->height-1); i++) {

        for (int j = 0;  j < (mpAVFrameInput->width-1); j++) {
        printf("\n value: %d",pic.data[0][j]);

        }

    }
```

Pseudo code which is in my mind is :

```
For each pixel in image {
Red = pic.data[i][j].pixel.RED;
Green = pic.data[i][j].pixel.GREEN;
Blue = pic.data[i][j].pixel.BLUE;
GRAY = (Red+Green+Blue)/3;
Red = GRAY;
Green = GRAY;
Blue = GRAY;
Save Frame;}
```

I am quite new to FFMPEG therefore any guidance and help will be highly appreciable.

Many Thanks

Comment: Why not use the swscale to perform the color conversion instead of doing it yourself?

Comment: I am planning to port this function in parallel manner and port it on CUDA.

Comment: Hmm, then maybe check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223315/video-decoder-on-cuda-ffmpeg. But if you are decoding H.264 or MPEG-4 I'd suggest to skip FFmpeg and use NVENC or some other GPU based decoding tehcnology, if you are already planning to use CUDA.

Comment: Just posted the answer, hope it can help someone else as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First extract the row data row-by-row of each frame; iterate the loop keeping in view the frame's height.

Here's the sample:

```
int FrameHeight = FrameInput->height;
        int FrameWidth = FrameInput->width;
        for(int Counter=0; Counter<FrameHeight; Counter++)
        {
            int RowSize = FrameWidth*sizeof(uint8_t)*3;
            uint8_t* RowData = (uint8_t*) malloc(RowSize);

            memset(RowData, 0, RowSize);

            memcpy(RowData, AVFrameInput->data[0]+Counter*AVFrameInput->linesize[0], RowSize);

            for(int k=0;k<AVFrameInput->linesize[0];++k)
            {

                if(RowData[k]> 200)
                {
                    RowData[k] = RowData[k]/3;

                }
                else
                {
                    if(RowData[k] > 150)
                    {
                        RowData[k] = RowData[k]/3;


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RowData[k] = RowData[k]/3;

                    }
                }


            } 

            memcpy(AVFrameInput->data[0]+Counter*AVFrameInput->linesize[0], RowData, RowSize);
        }
```